# How do I add an image over background colour?

Tags: html, css

How do I add an image over background colour? I want the image the to at the bottom of the div. I tried it with the code below but it doesn't seem to work for me. See code below:

```css
.teal {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: #2dd5c4;
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="teal">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo l. igula eget dolor. Aenean massa. <br />
    <button> Call to action</button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Note your typo in `<button> href="">`

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you mean by asking how to add an image over background color?

Comment: The image is at the bottom. But you haven’t given it a specific size and it is too tall for the container, notice the top of the roofs gets cut off. The image is also on top of the teal like color, try your snippet in full page. In landscape mode I see the teal on the sides.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try add the !important tag at the end of the background-image

```
background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg) !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put the image in a different div and put it over your teal class using z-index or having it as a child component to teal class
[z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

```
    <div class='teal' >
        <div class='image' > </div>
    <div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```css
background-image: url();
```